# How to load a NavBar in the collapsed state when it goes vertical on a small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and jquery and javascript and I am working on a website and I am down to one issue . . . I need the navbar at the top to load in a collapsed state on an Extra Small screen.  Right now, the bar goes vertical on an XS screen, but I want it to load in the collapsed state so that the user has to click the "three bar icon" on the right to load the page.  No matter what I do, I cannot get the navbar to load correctly.  If I load it collapsed on the small screen, it becomes invisible on a large screen.  I have been working on this for 2 days now.  I know it is something simple, but I just cannot figure it out.  Can someone else please help.

Here is the relevant code …

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-target">

  <header id="header">

    <!-- Navigation
      ================================================== -->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#page-top" style="font-size:1.5em;">Watch It Outside</a></li>
        <li id="drop"><a href="#" class="fa fa-align-justify visible-xs" style="position:absolute;right:40px; top:-40px;"></a></li>
        <li id="drop1"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li id="drop2"><a href="http://www.boston.gov/news" target="_blank">City Of Boston News</a></li>
        <li id="drop3"><a href="http://www.boston.gov/parks/public-garden" target="_blank">Boston Public Gardens</a></li>
        <li id="drop4"><a href="#films" class="collapse-sm collapse-xs collapse-md">Film Information</a></li>
        <li id="drop5"><a href="#register">Registration</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


  </header>
```

```
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Javascript and Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Scrollspy fluide
    $(function () {
      $('li>a').on('click', function (e) {
        var hash = this.hash;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
          window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      });
    });
  </script>



  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#drop').click(function() {
        $('#drop1').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop2').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop3').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop4').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop5').collapse('toggle');
      });

      $('#drop1').click(function() {
        $('#drop1').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop2').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop3').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop4').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop5').collapse('toggle');
      });
      $('#drop4').click(function() {
        $('#drop1').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop2').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop3').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop4').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop5').collapse('toggle');
      });
      $('#drop5').click(function() {
        $('#drop1').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop2').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop3').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop4').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop5').collapse('toggle');
      });
});
</script>
```

I am also getting a weird error that has recently popped up in the site where I now have to click a link twice to get it to close the first time.  From there, every click toggles it collapsed and expanded, but the first one takes 2 clicks to collapse the navbar.  (I don't know what I changed to cause this as it didn't start out that way)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like 
`if (device.width < 800) {
$("nav").addClass("collapsed");
}`

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I tried to add this into my script, with several variations.  Perhaps I don't understand it very well.  When I added this to the top of my script, the collapse feature quit working altogether.  (Even when I clicked on it.)  I also tried to use  ````      if (device.width < 800) {
        $('#drop1').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop2').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop3').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop4').collapse('toggle');
        $('#drop5').collapse('toggle');
      });````  And it didn't work either.